# Laravel - Restore Database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have used Laravel PHP framework to develop a website. I will backup a database from MySQL Server. I would like to restore a database to a new server.

Is it necessary to use migrate tools first such as `php artisan migrate` and then restore the data?

Comment: No that shouldn't be necessary. Just import the backup and you're good to go.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. In the future if I want to amend the tables, I should never edit the tables in MySQL Database directly.. use migrate tool instead? I have used migrate tool in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to run migrations when importing / restoring your backup.

Whether you want to use migrations or edit the MySQL database directly is up to you, but I recommend you are consistent about your decision.

Some advantages of migrations are:

1. You can easily set up a fresh, empty database
2. You can track the history of your database
3. You can roll back migrations
4. You can easily update a database instance to the newest version without having to do the steps manually.